# Sonar violation on "disallowed assignment of parameters"

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have the following code and I got an sonar violation error: `disallowed assignment of parameters`
What is the best way to fix this?

```
   /**
     * @param lastAccessTime the lastAccessTime to set
     */
    public void setLastAccessTime(Date lastAccessTime)
    {
        this.lastAccessTime = lastAccessTime == null ? null : new Date(lastAccessTime.getTime());
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect one of 2 things are happening here:

1 - There is a bug in the checkstyle plugin

2 - The code sonar analysed is not quite the code you posted here

I believe that violation should apply in the following case:

```
    /**
     * @param lastAccessTime the lastAccessTime to set
     */
    public void setLastAccessTime(Date lastAccessTime)
    {
        lastAccessTime = lastAccessTime == null ? null : new Date(lastAccessTime.getTime());
    }
```

So when you are reassigning the method parameter it would be expected, but in your example you are not, you are assigning it to a class field so it should be ok.

Try changing the method parameter to `final` and see if you still see the violation.